# AJAX/PHP Auto Display Updated Value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a simple question, I'm sure. I just don't know what I should be searching for on google. It'd probably be easier for me to explain:

For example I have a mysql field with the value 'Yes'

How do I with AJAX/PHP keeping querying the field for when the value changes to 'No'?

Could someone explain, in simple terms please

Comment: maybe `setInterval()` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two function that will help.

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
setInterval ( expression, interval );
```

Where `expression` is a function and `timeout` and interval are integers in `milliseconds`. `setTimeout` runs the timer once and runs the expression once whereas `setInterval` will run the expression every time the interval passes.

So in your case it would work something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //call $.ajax here
    $.ajax({

        url         : URL,
        data        : passData,
        dataType    : 'json', //or html or xml
        beforeSend  : function()
        {
            //this will execute before request is send
        },
        success     : function(response)
        {
            //check for response if( response ) { } else {  }
        }

    });
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```

**Now the backend php file.**

```
<?php

$passedVar = $_REQUEST['passedData']; //get data that were passed in ajax call
//database connection
//query to check for status
if(query return true)
{
    echo json_encode(true);
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(false);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a JavaScript function which will execute ajax call then put that function on  setInterval()

```
function ajaxcall(){

 // you ajax call;
}


 setInterval(ajaxcall, 10000);// change time by replacing 10000(time is in millisecond)
```

Here ajaxcall will be called in every 10 second.You can do anything inside ajaxcall function I mean checking your database value by ajax.